# Content resize ionic 2

Tags: tabs, ionic2, android-softkeyboard

I'm having a problem with usage of `content.resize()`; in tabs with native keyboard plugin. Can any anyone guide me how to use and where to use content resize with tabs when the content dimension changes due to native keyboard appearance? Below is the code I'm using:

```
this.keyboard.onKeyboardHide().subscribe(() => {
      this.isKeyboardHide = true;
      setTimeout(() => { 
        this.content.resize();
      }, 500);
    });
```

I'm unable to resize my child view content once the android keyboard appears. **[Here](https://github.com/VishwajeetBehera/Demo-Tab-and-Keyboard-Issuse)** is the sample code on github.